# Negotiation fails on KSZ8895 Micrel Switch IC

Tags: ethernet

Why does the negotiation with the network fail? The only common issue I found is the voltage gets a "load" which drops the pulse peak for a short time.

Here negotiation fails:
[image: No transsition occurs]

Here negotiation is ok:
[image: Propper transsition]

Comment: Tx diff outputs 2Vpp and Rx diff expects 400mVpp min with 100R terms.  Is there contention access here? with 50R term? can you show test points? Looks like an asymmetric response when invalid and symmetric when valid in yellow

Comment: the test points are the same. the only difference is board rev. How  can i fix the incorrect offset (prior to handshaking)?

Comment: Is it having a hard time negotiating between 10T and 100T base?

Comment: did you scope signal integrity at Rx end? which points are the same points?

Comment: The test points between the screen shots are the same. Signal after the transformer is very similar. the peak is 200mV less

Comment: To verify signal integrity, one should examine the individual pulses at the Rx and use calibrated 10:1 probes

Comment: The pulses individually look good.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the issue. It was the current setting resistor for the switch IC.

EDIT: The Switch IC has a resistor that sets the driving current of the differential pairs. It has to be 12.4k Ohms the 'k' was omitted on the BOM.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? and punctuate.

Answer (score 0):

If PHY signal integrity is an issue....

- Where do you start? grounds? cables? baluns? scope fast enough?? HDX? FDX?

  - for example of what can go wrong with a pulse from layout using TDR from Tek and showing causes.

[image]

Comment: I'm not using a PHY.